# Conditional SUM in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. When I was testing my code I noticed a problem.
Assume that max personal hour is 80 hours.

```
SELECT    
    lsm.EmployeeName,
    pd.absenceDate,
    pd.amountInDays * 8 AS [HoursReported],
    pd.status,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN pd.[status]='App' THEN (pd.amountInDays * 8)
              ELSE 0 END) OVER (partition by lsm.[EmployeeName] order by pd.absenceDate)) AS [TotalUsedHours]
          ( @maxPSHours ) - (sum(
              CASE WHEN pd.[status]='App' THEN (pd.amountInDays * 8)
                   ELSE 0 END)
          over (
              partition by  lsm.[EmployeeName] order by pd.absenceDate)) AS [TotalRemainingHours]
FROM    
    [LocationStaffMembers] lsm 
INNER JOIN 
    [PersonalDays] pd ON lsm.staffMemberId = pd.staffMemberId
```

This query returns these results:

```
EmployeeName AbsenceDate HoursReported   Status     TotalUsdHrs  TotalRemingHrs
 X            11/11/2015       4         approved     4             76
 X            11/15/2015       8         approved     12            68
 X            11/20/2015       2         decline      14            66
 X            11/20/2015       2         approved     14            66
```

So, query works fine for different status. First 2 rows are fine.  But when an employee does more than one action in a day (decline, approved etc.), my query only shows the total used and total remaining for the day.

Here is the expected result.

```
EmployeeName AbsenceDate HoursReported   Status     TotalUsdHrs  TotalRemingHrs
 X            11/11/2015       4         approved     4             76
 X            11/15/2015       8         approved     12            68
 X            11/20/2015       2         decline      12            68
 X            11/20/2015       2         approved     14            66
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a cumulative sum that returns results based on the order of `AbsenceDate` (`sum(...) over (partition by ... order by pd.absenceDate`).  But your last 2 records have the exact same date (`11/20/2015`) -- at least, according to what you are showing us. This creates an ambiguity.

So, it is absolutely conceivable, and legal, that SQL Server is processing the `2 approved hours` row *before* the `2 declined hours` row when calculating the cumulative sum --which would explain your current results--, despite the fact that rows themselves are returned to you in a different order (BTW, consider adding an `order by` clause to the query, otherwise, the order of the rows themselves are not guaranteed).

If the 2 rows do in fact share the exact same date, you'll have to find a 2nd column to remove the ambiguity and add that to the `order by` clause in the cumulative `sum` window function.  Maybe you could add a timestamp field that you can order by.

Or maybe you always want the `declined` status to be considered ahead of the `approved` status when the `AbsenceDate` is the same.  Here is an example of a query that would do exactly that (notice the changes in the `order by` clauses):

```
SELECT    
    lsm.EmployeeName,
    pd.absenceDate,
    pd.amountInDays * 8 AS [HoursReported],
    pd.status,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN pd.[status]='App' THEN (pd.amountInDays * 8)
              ELSE 0 END) OVER (partition by lsm.[EmployeeName] order by pd.absenceDate,
                                                                         case when pd.[status] = 'App' then 1 else 0 end)) AS [TotalUsedHours]
          ( @maxPSHours ) - (sum(
              CASE WHEN pd.[status]='App' THEN (pd.amountInDays * 8)
                   ELSE 0 END)
          over (
              partition by  lsm.[EmployeeName] order by pd.absenceDate,
                                                        case when pd.[status] = 'App' then 1 else 0 end)) AS [TotalRemainingHours]
FROM    
    [LocationStaffMembers] lsm 
INNER JOIN 
    [PersonalDays] pd ON lsm.staffMemberId = pd.staffMemberId
ORDER BY lsm.[EmployeeName],
         pd.absenceDate,
         case when pd.[status] = 'App' then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: I haven't really read through the whole problem...but wouldn't framing the window with `RANGE` fix it?

Comment: @shawnt00: No, I'm pretty sure it's just an ordering problem.